# Query posts which must exist in one of two categories, and another

Tags: php, wordpress

We are writing a custom search function for a Wordpress install. The setup is a little complex, but here's a stripped-back use case.

What we would like to do is to search all posts which:

a) Exist in **either** category: `[ 203, 204 ]`
b) **Must exist** in `2` as well

Initially, I thought we could combine `category__or` with `category__and`, but this is producing unexpected results (ignore the use of `category__not_in`):

```
Array
(
    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
            [0] => 202
            [1] => 205
        )

    [category__or] => Array
        (
            [0] => 203
            [1] => 204
        )

    [cateogory__and] => 139
    [offset] => 0
    [paged] => 1
    [posts_per_page] => 20
)
```

How do we find posts using `WP_Query()` using the requirements:
 `category = (203 && 2) || (204 && 2)`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. Do you mean posts that are in categories `(203 && 2) || (204 && 2)`?

Comment: @JordiNebot Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to deal with complex taxonomy queries I always prefer a [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead of dealing with the confusing `category__in`, `category__and`, etc. even when the taxonomy is the default *Category*.

```
<?php
$args = [
    'posts_per_page'   => 20,
    'tax_query'        => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [

            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => [203, 2],
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => [204, 2],
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ],
    ],
];

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```